# Secondary mathematical calculations on a Groupby besides just Sum

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to do a groupby along with several mathematical functions besides just Sum.

First I need to group by the "issue" name and "type." After that there counts, sums, averages, etc...

Currently I am doing a second database call on the same data (below).

What would be the best approach to doing it all with pandas and getting rid of the second database call?

Thanks.

the dataframe:

```
 action  code comm   credit date        debit  \
0  +     P  1309.28   0.00  2009-06-25  52371.00   
1  +     P  2397.49   0.00  2009-07-31  47949.81   
2  +     P   749.78   0.00  2011-05-27  14995.65   

    issue                                              price  \
0   PR SALES TAX FING CORP RETAIL SR B RV DUE 0801...  0.1746   
1   TAX FREE PUERTO RICO FUND II INC                   8.5600   
2   PUERTO RICO FIXED INCOME FD III INC                8.6400   

   shares      type  
0  300000.000  finc  
1    5601.000  mfds  
2    1735.000  mfds
```

database equivalent:

```
cons = c.trades_set.all () \
    .values ( 'issue', 'type' ) \
    .annotate (
    cnt = Count ( 'issue' ),
    debit = Sum ( 'debit' ),
    credit = Sum ( 'credit' ),
    shrs = Sum ( 'shares' ) / 2,
    price = Avg ( 'price' ),
    ).order_by ( 'type', 'issue' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution. I've invented some data to demonstrate the principle.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'issue': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
                   'type': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y'],
                   'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                   'col2': [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                   'col3': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18],
                   'col4': [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]})

g = df.groupby(['issue', 'type'], as_index=False).agg({'col1': 'count', 'col2': 'sum',
                                                       'col3': lambda x: sum(x)/2,
                                                       'col4': lambda x: sum(x)/len(x)})

#   issue type  col1  col2  col3  col4
# 0     A    X     2    16  14.0  19.0
# 1     B    X     1     8   7.0  19.0
# 2     B    Y     1    10   8.0  21.0
# 3     C    Y     2    23  17.5  22.5
```

Comment: This seems to work, never used the lambda before. Is there anyway to add this into the formula?  just want  to keep things clean and inclusive: g['profit'] = g.credit - g.debit

Comment: @diogenes, no - `agg` is only used on `groupby` objects to group across a column by groups.